# Julia set of finite Blaschke product

Tags: rational-functions, visualization, complex-dynamics, blaschke-products

I want to compute the Julia set of  finite Blaschke product $B_3$  from [the second version of the paper "PARABOLIC AND NEAR-PARABOLIC RENORMALIZATION FOR LOCAL DEGREE THREE" by FEI YANG,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.00043v2.pdf),  see Figure 14 from page 52

$$B_3 = (\frac{z+1/2}{z/2+1})^3$$

First I should [analyze the map](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/analysis) so I compute first derivative :

$$ (3*(z+1/2)^2)/(z/2+1)^3-(3*(z+1/2)^3)/(2*(z/2+1)^4) $$

and critical point ( z for which derivative is equal to zero)

$$ z = -1/2 $$

Results of the analysis:

- $B_3$ is a Blaschke product whose Julia set is the unit circle
- The point z = 1 is a 1-parabolic fixed point with two attracting petals
- there is only one critical point z=-1/2
- the unit disk $D$ and $C \setminus D$ are two immediate basins of
  parabolic fixed point
- poles: z = -2 (order 3 pole)
- zeros: z = -1/2 (order 3 zero)

Now I can create attracting petal ( trap). It is a a disc inside component with parabolic fixed point in its boundary

[image: attractig petal = trap]

Then I try to compute the dynamical chessboard ( I use [binary decomposition of attracting petal](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/pcheckerboard))

My image
[image]

is different then that from the paper. It looks like 1/3 of original image.
[image]

Where is my error ?  Are there other critical points?

Here is [my program](https://github.com/adammaj1/dynamical-chessboard-of-Blaschke-product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer in another paper on similar topic : [Near Parabolic Renormalization for Unicritical Holomorphic Maps by Arnaud Chéritat](http://amj.math.stonybrook.edu/pdf-Springer-final/020-0172.pdf)

It is dynamical chessboard of not $B_3$ but of normalized $B_3$ denoted as $\tilde{B_3}$

In general:

$$\tilde{B_d}= \frac{z^d + a}{1 + az^d }$$

where
$$a = \frac{d − 1}{d + 1}$$

so for d=3

$$\tilde{B_3}= \frac{z^3 + \frac{1}{2}}{1 + \frac{z^3}{2} }$$

Now images :are good for "every" $d >= 2$

[image: d=2]

[image: d=3]

[image: d=4]

[image: d=5]

[image: d=6]

[code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dynamical_chessboards_of_Blaschke_product_f(z)_%3D_(z%5Ed_%2B_a)_over_(1_%2B_a*z%5Ed)_with_a_%3D_(d_-_1)_over_(_d_%2B_1)_for_d_%3D_3.png#%7B%7Bint%3Afiledesc%7D%7D)